# How to animate images in uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a image slide shows by setting image from url and on touch on sliding image then make a call below is my json

```
 "id":"21",
        "title":"Example Name",
        "image":"http://example.com/image/mblads/imagename.jpg",
        "phn":"+911234567890"
```

I have tried with transition animation but I couldn't make

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What precisely do you need help with?

Comment: Your question is not clear to understand , please try to add some details

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kimar/KIImagePager

This library is written in objective-c with easy code & its implement in your project easily.